# Select and calculate columns - SQLite

Tags: android, sql

Could you tell me what's wrong with this code ??

```
public Cursor IMC(){
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] campos =  {"SELECT (peso/(altura*altura)) FROM medidas "};
        db = banco.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.query(CriaBanco.TABELA_MEDIDAS, campos, null, null, null, null, null, null);



        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.close();
        return cursor;
    }
```

(peso/(altura*altura) are columns and "medidas" the table...

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.resultado__imc_layout);

            BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
            Cursor cursor = crud.IMC();

            String[] nomeCampos = new String[] {"SELECT (peso/(altura*altura) FROM medidas "};
            int[] idViews = new int[] {R.id.txtresultado_imc};



        }
```

I'm trying to show the result of the SELECT equation in the textview "txtresultado_imc"...

Below the table code

```
public class CriaBanco extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "banco.db";
    private static final int VERSAO = 1;


    static final String TABELA_MEDIDAS = "medidas";
    static final String CODIGO = "codigo";
    static final String ALTURA = "altura" ;
    static final String PESO = "peso" ;
    static final String CINTURA = "cintura" ;
    static final String PESCOCO = "pescoco" ;
    static final String QUADRIL = "quadril" ;
    static final String GRAU_ATIVIDADE = "grau_atividade" ;


    public CriaBanco(Context context) {
        super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        String medidas = "CREATE TABLE medidas (" 

                    + "codigo integer primary key autoincrement," 
                    + "altura integer,"
                    + "peso integer,"
                    + "cintura integer,"
                    + "pescoco integer,"
                    + "quadril integer,"
                    + "grau_atividade num)";

        db.execSQL(medidas);
    }
```

Tks!

Comment: welcome to so , your question lacks the essential points i.e. explanation about what this code should do and what is currently happening so add these details plus if there is any exception then please add logcat details

Comment: At least one issue is that the second argument in your [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) statement is supposed to be for the columns you want to return.

Comment: Pavneet Singh, 
I need the select to take the values ​​of the columns "peso" and "altura" and perform the equation (peso/(altura*altura)) and then show in the textview ... It will not be called a button, when opening the screen the value should already be there ....

Answer (score 0):

In your query closing bracket is missing.

Use this

```
"SELECT (peso/(altura*altura)) FROM medidas"
```

Instead of

```
"SELECT (peso/(altura*altura) FROM medidas "
```

Then use result of `cursor` to set data on `TextView`.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtresultado_imc);    
 // set result
tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(0));)

 // Remove these below lines, I don't know what you are trying to achieve with them. They are looking unused and unnecessary

String[] nomeCampos = new String[] {"SELECT (peso/(altura*altura) FROM medidas "};
int[] idViews = new int[] {R.id.txtresultado_imc};
```

One more observation which you need to modify, for making your code working. Your method is accepting string while your column type is allowed to insert integer values only.

```
public String insereMedidas(String altura, String peso, String cintura, String pescoco, String quadril, String grau_atividade)
```

This should be -

```
public String insereMedidas(int altura, int peso, int cintura, int pescoco, int quadril, int grau_atividade)
```

Cross check data types are same for all columns. And while getting text from your EditText convert it into `int`, but make sure only numeric value is allowed as input.

For eg -

```
int pesoValue = Integer.parseInt(Peso.getText().toString());
```

Pass above value to insert method, do same for all inputs.

Comment: Where you are saving/inserting data in table?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded SQLite Expert and it is running normal ... I discovered that the problem is in the equation ...(peso+altura)  It works but (peso/(altura*altura)) returns empty...

Comment: I am asking for code, where you are inserting data in your table

Comment: `public Cursor IMC(){
  Cursor cursor;
  String[] campos =  {"SELECT (peso/(altura*altura)) FROM medidas WHERE codigo = (SELECT codigo FROM medidas ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1)"};

  db = banco.getReadableDatabase();

  cursor = db.query("medidas", campos, null, null, null, null, null, null);

  if(cursor!=null){
   cursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  db.close();
  return cursor;
 }`

Comment: The above method is being called in that code that you passed me earlier

Comment: Where you are inserting data in database

Comment: `public String insereMedidas(String altura, String peso, String cintura, String pescoco, String quadril, String grau_atividade) {
ContentValues medidas;
long resultado_medidas;
db = banco.getWritableDatabase();
medidas = new ContentValues();
medidas.put("altura", altura);
medidas.put("peso", peso);
medidas.put("cintura", cintura);
medidas.put("pescoco", pescoco);
medidas.put("quadril", quadril);
medidas.put("grau_atividade", grau_atividade);
resultado_medidas = db.insert("medidas", null, medidas);
db.close();
`

Comment: continuation `if (resultado_medidas == -1)
return "Erro ao inserir registro";
else
return "Registro Inserido com sucesso";
}`

Comment: From where you are calling this method - insereMedidas

Comment: Sorry... I'm a beginner...`public void salvar() {
String txtAltura = Altura.getText().toString();
String txtPeso = Peso.getText().toString();
String txtCintura = Cintura.getText().toString();
String txtPescoco = Pescoco.getText().toString();
String txtQuadril = Quadril.getText().toString();
String spnGrauAtividade = GrauAtividade.getSelectedItem().toString();
BancoController bd = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
String resultado_medidas;
resultado_medidas = bd.insereMedidas(txtAltura, txtPeso, txtCintura, txtPescoco, txtQuadril, spnGrauAtividade);
`

Comment: Continuation... `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resultado_medidas, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
limpar();}`

Comment: I changed all numeric entries to int, but it still does not work ... There are only two things to run the program: select perform the equation (weight / (height * height)) and show method in textview (which at the moment does not show Nor the value of a single column ....